# Alternatives to Card.getText() in CardBuilder

Tags: google-glass

After the latest update for Glass, my code is essentially broken because of the deprecation of the Card.getText() method. What would be a painless alternative to this method?

.toString is of no use because of the Object return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getters were deprecated because `CardBuilder` is not designed to be used as the data model for your application; it should only be used to plug in data and get views back out. If you need to retain information that you can query later, you should just design your own objects to contain that information (and then you might add a simple method/factory that creates `CardBuilder`s from those objects).

Comment: But how can i get my card information if i will go own object. How can i get object from  card?